# Selecting records from database mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Im looking for a way that I can get candidates result in a voting session.

[image]

See Image above.
Candidate Id 5 has been voted in by 3 voters, making it 3 votes.
Candidate Id 4 has been voted in by 1 voter, making it 1 vote.

So candidate Id 5 wins by 3 votes against Candidate Id 4 with 1 vote.

I need a query that can group this results by department eg. hospital, and show the candidates with their respective votes count in order from top to last candidate

Comment: what have you tried? We need more info of all the tables that shall be used. do have some SQL that you have tested first before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(voter_ID) as votecount, candidate_id from tablename group by candidate_id, position order by votecount
```

You can group by two column like candidate_id and position.
[image]